# Java for loop explanation

Tags: java, for-loop

I would appreciate some help on this code which I found inside a program but I could not understand it, I have guessed what it does by commenting it, but please correct me if I am wrong.

```
 for(String[] movieArray:movie)
        {
            for(String data:movieArray)
            {
                if(data!=null){ //If data is not empty then it writes...
                jTextArea1.append(data+", "); //...this to the textarea.
                }
                else{ //If data is empty, then it will stop.
                empty=true;
                break;
                }
            }
            if(empty==false){ //??
            jTextArea1.append("\n"); 
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What type of object is `movie`?

Comment: By the way, it's better if you change this to `if(!empty)`.

Comment: @AJ. it looks like String[][]

Comment: I think user3042022 is confused with the enhanced for loop

Comment: @AJ OP's question says something else than what answers which are posted below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After all the elements in the array `movieArray` were not `null`, then they would be appended to `jTextArea1` and the `empty` would stay `false`(provided it was `false` initially).

And after the inner `for` is over, it appends a new line character(`\n`) if `empty` was `false`(this would happen if the condition in the first statement satisfied), else if the `empty` was set to `true`(there was a `null` element in the array), then it would not print the new line character.

Here is how you can better understand it with an example.

```
movie = {{"1", "2", "3"}, {"4", "5", "6"}}; // Example 1
```

`jTextArea1` would be

```
1, 2, 3, 
4, 5, 6,
```

And if

```
movie = {{"1", null, "3"}, {"4", "5", "6"}}; // Example 2
```

`jTextArea1` would be

```
1, 4, 5, 6,
```

That's because in the second case, one of the elements of the array was `null` and thus it broke out of the `for` after setting `empty` as `true`. And since empty was `true`, it did not print the new line character.

Answer (score 0):

Your comments are right.

```
/**if no one of the data objects is empty, the boolean `empty` is 
 *still false and then a \n is added to the textarea.
 */
if(empty==false){ 
    jTextArea1.append("\n"); 
}
```

`empty==false` is the same as `!empty`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like broken for to me ..

```
 if(empty==false){ //??
  jTextArea1.append("\n"); 
 }
```

should be inside the for loop

Answer (score 0):

```
 for(String[] movieArray:movie)
```

This means - loop will continue until there is a value present in movie array.
It is equivalent to

```
for(int i =0; i<movie.length();i++)
    String [] movieArray = movie[i];
```

WHile 2nd for loop i.e. `for(String data:movieArray)`
means the `movieArray` that you have created earlier is used here. This loop will continue to execute till there are elements present in `movieArray`.

Following is the representation of enhanced for loop you've mentioned.

```
for(int i =0; i<movie.length();i++){
   for(int j = 0; j<movie[0].length(); j++){
```